# Adding a UITableVIew on to a View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

When a user clicks on a Button, i slide in a `UIView` (This `UIVIew` is created via a `XIB` file).

I have added a `TableView` to this `XIB` file and connected the `datasource` and `delegate` as well. See image below:

[image]

In the View class i have added the following method.

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    [self addSubview:self. tablev];

}
```

In the Header file i have the following code.

```
@interface FlipView : UIView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

The code for the `UIViewController` class. There's a button in this class, and when the user clicks on it the `UIView` will show. The code that will be executed when the button is clicked.

```
fv = [[FlipView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];

[self.view addSubview:fv];

[self.view addSubview: fv];
```

The `view` pops up perfectly with the tableview. However, the content on the tableview are not populated. When i debugged the code i found out that the delegate methods are not called. How can i solve this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCell

 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"c" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)

    {

        cell = [[MyCell

 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

                                             reuseIdentifier:@"c"];

    }

    cell.la.text=@"hiiiii";
```

Comment: pls show full code, I think numberOfRow = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data source and the delegate are connected to the File's owner and *NOT* the FlipView. You can remove the delegate and data source from xib, and add it programatically:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

I suggest doing that in the initWithFrame method.

Comment: I added breakpoints. It still doesn't go into `cellforrowatindexpath`

Comment: Does the set delegate and data source called?

Comment: yes. when i add the breakpoints it executed those lines. Help.

Comment: My guess it that you table view is still nil there. Can you check?

Comment: How do i check if its `nil`?

Comment: Put a break point on the line: self.tableView.delegate = self; and check the self property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73790/discussion-between-asaf-and-illep).